# android camera2 preview lag when getting frame

Tags: preview, android-camera2, screen-capture, previewcallback, image-reader

I am using Android camera2 in order to extract frames in real time in preview mode to stitch them in NDK side(openCv).
I use `ImageReader` surface to get frames, but it is limited to a max frame value.

```
ImageReader.newInstance(800,600,ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, MAX_FRAME);
```

it works good but since we need all frames, must remove `ImageReader` target surface from `CaptureRequest.Builder` and add it again. so we have a lag at this point.

How can we have an `ImageReader` without max frame or how can we get all frames from live video in camera2 without any lag in preview?

My code:

```
    private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        try {

            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mPreviewCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
//                    closePreviewSession();
                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    try {
                        session.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            };
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, mPreviewCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void addImageReaderSurface() {
        try {

            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            newImageReader(10);
            surfaces.add(mImageReader.getSurface());
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            mPreviewCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    mPreviewSession = session;
                    try {
                        mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            };
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, mPreviewCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void newImageReader(final int count) {
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(800, 600, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, count);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                index++;
                Log.e("xxx", "frame " + index + " received");
                if (index == count) {
                    index = 0;
//                    remove it before reached max value
                    addImageReaderSurface();
                }
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to restart the ImageReader. MAX_FRAME is the queue size, and will never get full if your callback is quick enough, and the preview frames will continuesly flow in.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

After acquiring an image from the reader with `Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage()`, you must call `img.close()`.

```
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
    if (img == null) { return; }
    // do work
    img.close();
}
```